# C# concert ticket, simple switch, case, and if-else

Tags: c#

Program Specification: The purpose of this application will be to calculate the cost for concert tickets.
The individual ticket cost is based on where the tickets are located. Based on the number of tickets
ordered, a percentage off discount will be applied to the total cost. Finally, if the customer is a preferred
customer, they will receive $10 off their order

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double Box = 75.25;
    double Pavillion = 30.75;
    double Lawn = 21.50;
    double Tickets;
    double discount;
    int Number;

    Number = 0;
    discount = ;

    if (int.TryParse(numberofTicketsTextbox.Text, out Number))
    else MessageBox.Show("Invalid");

    if (boxRadioButton.Checked)
        singleTicketLabel.Text = Box.ToString();

    if (pavilionRadioButton.Checked)
        singleTicketLabel.Text = Pavillion.ToString();

    if (lawnRadioButton.Checked)
        singleTicketLabel.Text = Lawn.ToString();

    switch(discount)
    {
        case_1:

    }
}
```

I just don't know how to get the Case started to include the discount

Comment: Where does discount get set? How can you tell if the customer is preferred? Why are you using a switch?

Comment: `a percentage off discount will be applied to the total cost`.  Doesn't sound like you need a switch block.

Comment: Presumably then the rules are like "if volume is between X and Y then discount is z" - you can't express that in a switch statement.

Comment: You could if this was vb =)

Comment: For the assignment it is asking me to use a switch statement

Comment: If you really need to use a switch statement, look up the syntax for it and shove it in there. If it is proving problematic update the question with the exact problem.

Comment: So, you need a switch based on the number of tickets sold?

Comment: Yes, the discount is Determine the discount total cost based on the following criteria.
 If a person purchases 3 or fewer tickets – they do not receive a discount.
 If they purchase 4 – 6 tickets, there is a 5 % discount
 If they purchase more than 6 tickets – they receive a 10% discount.
 For this logic – use the Switch decision control structure logic.

Comment: Try read about patterns. It will give you flexibility with calculation - I wouldn't be sure that your criteria will change in the future.

Comment: Don't you think that discount breakdown would have been relevant information in your question?

Comment: @jake this is something that you could have figured out on your own in regards to how to construct a `switch case statement` why do you not use google..?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be useful - adapted straight from the [MSDN reference on Switch statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/06tc147t.aspx)

```
double discount = 0;
switch (Number)   // <-- AWFUL name for a variable by the way
{
    case 1:       // For one ticket
        discount = 0.9;   // For 10%
        break;
    case 2:       // For two
    case 3:       // or three tickets
        discount = 0.8;   // For 20%
        break;
    default:
        discount = 1;
        break;
}

price -= price_before_discount * discount
```

Bear in mind as soon as one condition of the switch statement is made then the other options are not assessed and the switch breaks out.

Comment: I wish to state here for the record that `number` is not a bad name for "number of tickets" in a routine that deals with numbers of tickets and no other numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As there is already an answer just another hint:

You can exchange

```
if (int.TryParse(numberofTicketsTextbox.Text, out Number))
else MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
```

with

```
if (!int.TryParse(numberofTicketsTextbox.Text, out Number))
   MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
```

Notice the difference. In your code you had an empty block after the `if` statement and just used the `else` block. By negating with `!` you now can use the block of the `if` statement itself.